# How to use IMvxTrace in MvvmCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, logging, mvvmcross

Recently I started to study Xamarin and today I opened big project written on MvvmCross, and I have to add new features there. That is difficult as usually I work with Java and Android Studio, but now I have to deep in C# and Visual Studio.

Firstly I want to understand the flow of this project and for this I want to insert logs in different .cs classes and see them while navigate through the app.

In Setup.cs:

```
protected override IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace()
    {
        return new NLogTrace();
    }
```

NLogTrace.cs:

```
public class NLogTrace : IMvxTrace
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public NLogTrace()
    {
        InitializeNLog();

        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MvvmCross");
    }

    public static string LogFileName => Path.Combine(GetCacheFolder(), "logFile.txt");

    private static void InitializeNLog()
    {
        // Step 1. Create configuration object 
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

        // Step 2. Create targets and add them to the configuration 
        var consoleTarget = new ConsoleTarget();
        config.AddTarget("console", consoleTarget);

        var logFolderPath = GetCacheFolder();
        var fileTarget = new FileTarget
        {
            FileName = Path.Combine(logFolderPath, "logFile.txt"),
            ArchiveFileName = Path.Combine(logFolderPath, "log.{#}.txt"),
            ArchiveEvery = FileArchivePeriod.Day,
            ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.Date,
            MaxArchiveFiles = 7
        };
        config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);

        // Step 3. Set target properties 
        consoleTarget.Layout = @"${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"; //
        fileTarget.Layout = "${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}";

        // Step 4. Define rules
        var rule1 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, consoleTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule1);

        #if DEBUG
        var rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);
        #else
        var rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Info, fileTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);
        #endif

        LogManager.Configuration = config;
    }

    private static string GetCacheFolder()
    {
        var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var relativeCacheFolderPath = Path.Combine(documents, "Storage", "Logs");

        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(relativeCacheFolderPath);
        var resolvedCacheFolderPath = directory.FullName;
        return resolvedCacheFolderPath;
    }

    public void Trace(MvxTraceLevel level, string tag, string message)
    {
        switch (level)
        {
            case MvxTraceLevel.Diagnostic:
                _logger.Debug(message);
                break;
            case MvxTraceLevel.Warning:
                _logger.Warn(message);
                break;
            case MvxTraceLevel.Error:
                _logger.Error(message);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void Trace(MvxTraceLevel level, string tag, Func<string> message)
    {
        switch (level)
        {
            case MvxTraceLevel.Diagnostic:
                _logger.Debug(message());
                break;
            case MvxTraceLevel.Warning:
                _logger.Warn(message());
                break;
            case MvxTraceLevel.Error:
                _logger.Error(message());
                break;
        }
    }

    public void Trace(MvxTraceLevel level, string tag, string message, params object[] args)
    {
        switch (level)
        {
            case MvxTraceLevel.Diagnostic:
                _logger.Debug(message, args);
                break;
            case MvxTraceLevel.Warning:
                _logger.Warn(message, args);
                break;
            case MvxTraceLevel.Error:
                _logger.Error(message, args);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

So, I see some logger but I don't have any idea how to use it in some .cs file.
Can you provide some snippet how to use

```
Trace(MvxTraceLevel level, string tag, string message)
```

in arbitrarily chosen .cs file from .Core or .Droid projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to utilize Dependency injection. For complete documentation [see docs](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/logging). In short, you add a `IMvxLog` parameter in your view model/service constructor:

```
public MyViewModel( IMvxLog logger )
{
   this._logger = logger;
}
```

And then just call appropriate method on `_logger`:

```
_log.Trace("Some message");
```

If you want to use `IMvxLog` from a class where you cannot setup dependency injection, you can use `Mvx` to resolve it:

```
var logger = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxLog>();
```

Comment: I use Mvx.Resolve in .Core and .Droid projects but IMvxLog is not seen. In the project is used MvvmCross v.4.0